# Condition on case statement based on previous colum value in postgresql

Tags: sql

i am using select query like

```
select  case when sd.status=0 then 'ADD' else 'DELETE' end as  status ,statusval,
case when status ='ADD' then 0 else if status = 'DELETE' then 1 else 2 end as action
from status_data sd;
```

Since i have already got the value in field `status` as either `ADD or DELETE` wanted to use `status` further to get action but getting error on this.

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  (2) SQL does not allow you to reuse an column alias in the same `select` where it is defined.  (3) SQL case expressions have to `else if`.  Your question is quite unclear.  Sample data and desired results as well as an appropriate database tag and explanation would help.

Comment: What scenarios will you want to see as 2 in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using sub-query. I hope below answers your question:

```
Select statusval, 
case when status = 'ADD' THEN 0
     WHEN status = 'DELETE' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END action from
(select  case when sd.status=0 then 'ADD' else 'DELETE' end as  status ,statusval
from status_data sd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sd.status=0 
            THEN 'ADD' 
            ELSE 'DELETE' 
            END AS  status ,
        statusval,
        CASE WHEN sd.status = 0 
             THEN 0 
             WHEN sd.status <> 0  
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 2 
             END as action
FROM status_data sd;
```